# Declaring a constant in swift

Tags: ios, swift

As I read the [swift guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-XID_1) it says: `The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time, but you must assign it a value exactly once.`

I tried in REPL but without any luck:

```
let aConst;
aConst=23;
```

So how to declare a constant without setting initial value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example

```
let myConstant = getSomeValueFromMethod()
```

This is what it means that the value doesn't have to be known at compile time...

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a constant, then assign it at the global scope. If you have to do something like this, use a variable instead. When a constant is declared at global scope, it must be initialized with a value.

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_506)

Comment: But what does this mean `The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time` ?

Comment: You can have constants as properties of classes also. Those do not have to be declared with a value.

Comment: The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time, but you must assign it a value exactly once. This means you can use constants to name a value that you determine once but use in many places according to apple doc.

Comment: probably what I am testing is not possible in REPL ?

Comment: you should be able to create a class in REPL. Try adding a property on a class and you can declare it as a constant and set its value later

Answer (score 0):

You can't just declare a constant without assigning it some sort of value. The compiler needs to know that the constant will have some sort of value. Consider the following example where a constant "isTablet" is computed based on variables that aren't known until runtime.

```
let isTablet = {
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example beside Suthan's:

var someVar: NSString

...

someVar = "Some String"

let someUnknownConstant = someVar